# How to display distance between current lat long to specific lat long onto camera view in xamarin forms for android?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, arcore

**I am working in xamarin forms.** I want to display the distance from current location(lat, long) to specific location(lat, long) onto camera view.

I have achieved the same thing in IOS using following reference link.
https://github.com/pmourfield/Xamarin.Forms.ARToolkit/tree/master/test

but I can't able to find any reference to Android.

**I want to achieve the same functionality on Android.**

Answer (score 1):

For iOS since iOS 11 it's a native functionality for some devices. I would propose you to test your app over iPhone 5s or 6, since they have ability to upgrade to iOS 11, but they does not have such functionality.

Regarding Android, there is no build in thing for that in the system, so you would need to use any other solutions that allows to determinate the distance between you and points on the img. Or you can try go get the focus distance from the camera:
https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Hardware.Camera+Parameters.GetFocusDistances/p/System.Single%5b%5d/

Comment: The main thing is to display text over camera view in the direction towards some location (latitude and longitude). Calculating distance is secondary.

Comment: if you know the location of the phone and the location of the item, you could achieve that. The only problem is to understand which way the phone is facing, for that I would advice you to use a compass https://github.com/JarleySoft/CompassPlugin

Comment: Oh, you might be able to do it with Forms Labs: https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs